# I need to print 20,000 Word documents, is there a 3rd party tool that will help me do this or do I need to write custom code?

Tags: ms-word

I need to print 20,000 Word documents. Naturally this is a logistical nightmare. For example: if the power goes out, I need some software that will be able to resume where the printing failed. Also, this is something that needs to be done once a month by our client.

Do I have to write my own code to manage this? (Word Automation)

Or does anyone know of a tool that will help me do this? (Googling has not given me any good options. And I'm willing to pay!)

Comment: Do you really need to print them. For the sake of whatever gods you believe in, please, think of the *trees.* :-)

Comment: I know, it sounds like a crazy problem, but it's government documents and it definitely has to be printed.

Comment: Yeah, when I first saw the question, I thought "this has to be a DoD job" but I guess other branches of the gub'ment can be stupid as well :-)

Answer (score 11):

Outsource the job to a specialist printing company.

Answer (score 6):

1. Put your 20,000 documents in one folder
2. Press Ctrl-A to select all
3. Right click on 'print'

Note - there are many commercial printing houses which do this very thing.  Often they provide an API to send Word or PDF documents.  They'll even put the documents in a envelope and put them in the mail.  This is how most banks and credit card companies send you your monthly statements.

Comment: Sounds simple, but I need something a little more robust. I.e. what happens when the job fails (i.e. power goes out). I would have to be able to resume, hence the need for custom software or a third party tool.

Comment: I'd suggest putting BOTH your printer and your PC on a UPS before you hit the print button.  Otherwise, for recovery, check the last document which the printer successfully printed, and re-start your job from there.

Comment: If you write your own code, it can make things even worse, if there is a bug in the code. For me the Ctrl+A, Print and manual resuming from the last printed document sounds plenty robust. To save costs, let the intern do it.

Comment: step 4... sleep next to printer, feeding it new paper in your sleep

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm on Windows, I always use [AutoIT](http://autoitscript.com) for automation and/or repetitive tasks. It comes with a bunch of user-libraries, including one Microsoft Word, and it's very nice to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I would try AutoIT: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do this in any language which has an OLE capability. Most popular languages do, e.g. I know that Perl does.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the problem. In a perfect world, all the 20k documents would be in the same folder, ready to be printed. Just... print?

Are you referring to the logistical problems? 20k documents can sure be heavy to carry around, but thats not a question for SO. Why would you need custom code for that?

Or do you lack a printer with sufficient capabilities? If your printer is to slow, old or inaccurate there are companies that handle printing for you.